# Completing sequence pattern

Tags: pattern-recognition, pattern-matching

My kid is class 5
He has got a question of patterns

The pattern goes on as 13 15 27 42 .....
and have to find the next number with the rule pattern

I am unable to decode, thought question is incorrect but it is not 
Can any help on decoding the next digit following the pattern with reason

Comment: Looks random.  Perhaps it's values for  $-(7 x^3)/6 + (17 x^2)/2 - (16 x)/3 + 13$, though I doubt it.  Perhaps it's the numbers of the starting lineup of the kids' football team.  Without some context, it really could be anything.

Comment: if it was $12$, it will be a Fibonacci series!

Comment: Indeed it could be anything, for example:(13+15)-1=27, 15+27=42, (27+42)-1=68, 68+42=110, (68+110)-1=177 . . .

Comment: I guess that sirous's suggestion is partially right, I think, we have $13+15-1=27$ $15+27+0=42$ $27+42+1=70$ and so on, but alternating $-1$ and $0$ could be a solution as well. Already the existence of these two very plausible solutions expose that the exercise is ill-posed.

Comment: Hard to understand that the author only gives $4$ numbers, this is only sufficient in very obvious cases (and even then, another plausible solution might exist) !